# Replace column text values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have this database I created and now they want to add issues, which I decided it could be easier just assigning values.  So now I have a set of `<td class="issues">` outputting these values.

1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4
1
1 4 5

Now I'm trying to assign font awesome tags  to replace each number with a font icon
 i.e.:Line 1 will be `<i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

So far I got it to fetch the content and return the nodeType, just need to figure out how to replace the numbers with a case or if statement.

```js
    
      $( ".issues" ).contents().filter(function(){
          return this.nodeType === 3;
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Find replace</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="issues">1 2 3 4 5</div>
    <div class="issues">2 3 4</div>
    <div class="issues">1 </div>
    <div class="issues">1 4 5</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

My table:

```
<table>
    <tr data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="{{query1.data}}">
        <td style="display:none" data-row="{{id}}" ></td>
        <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{state}}</td>
        <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data1}}</td>
        <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data2}}</td>
        <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data3}}</td>
        <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data4}}</td>
        <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{total}}</td>
        <td class="small tb-data-off issues">{{issues}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what should be line 2?

Comment: you want to add icon for each number in `issues` like 1 for `heart-icon` 2 for `home-icon` ?

Comment: Actually  its a table with 15 columns and the last row has class="issues", so I think I do have to filter it?

Comment: M. Tanzil - yes that the idea.

Comment: `<table>
<tr data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="{{query1.data}}">
<td style="display:none" data-row="{{id}}" ></td>
    <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{state}}</td>
    <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data1}}</td>
    <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data2}}</td>
    <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data3}}</td>
    <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{data4}}</td>
    <td class="tb-info text-xs-center">{{total}}</td>

    <td class="small tb-data-off issues">{{issues}}</td>
    </tr>

 </table>`

Answer (score 1):

To do this we have to check every `word` of `issues` so we will wrap the words inside `span` so it will be easy to read the words,

**Check snippet** hope this is what you want.

```js
$(function(){
  var issues = $(".issues").length;
  for($i = 0; $i <= issues; $i++ ){
    var ic_i = $(".issues:eq("+$i+") span").length;
    for($k = 0; $k <= ic_i; $k++){
      var curr = $(".issues:eq("+$i+") span:eq("+$k+")" );
   // use your Conditional statmenst here.  
   // inside indexOf('') check for what you want 
   var isContains = $(curr).text(). indexOf('1') > -1;
      //
      
 if(isContains){                
   // replace your icon here
   $(curr).html("icon");

     }
    }
   }
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Find replace</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="issues"><span>1</span> <span>2</span>    <span>3</span> <span>4</span> <span>5</span></div>
    
    <div class="issues"><span>2</span> <span>3</span> <span>4</span></div>
    
    <div class="issues"><span>5</span></div>
    
    <div class="issues"><span>1</span> <span>2</span><span>3</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's my approach to your problem:

```
$('.issues').each(function() {
  var $issue = $(this);
  var icons = ['heartbeat', 'calculator', 'compass', 'eraser', 'diamond']; //Set your icons
  var text = $issue.text(); // Cache the text
  $issue.empty(); // Clear the current text

  for (var i = 1; i < icons.length + 1; i++) { // Create icons corresponding to the numbers
    if (text.indexOf(String(i)) > -1) {
      $('<i />', {
        'aria-hidden': 'true',
        'class': 'fa fa-' + icons[i - 1],
      }).appendTo($issue);
    }
  }
});
```

[See the live preview here.](https://jsfiddle.net/mx610yc1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` to loop each `.issues` div and then use `map()` to change numbers to icons.

```js
$('.issues').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().trim().split(' ').map(function(e) {
    return '<i class="fa fa-' + e + '" aria-hidden="true">Icon' + e + ' </i>';
  }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="issues">1 2 3 4 5</div>
<div class="issues">2 3 4</div>
<div class="issues">1</div>
<div class="issues">1 4 5</div>
```

Comment: How do I assign the valued to the map()?

Comment: Where do you want to assign value ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your HTML, a simple chained **replace** should do the trick:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.issues').html(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.replace('1', '<i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>').
               replace('2', '<i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>').
               replace('3', '<i class="fa fa-compass" aria-hidden="true"></i>').
               replace('4', '<i class="fa fa-erasor" aria-hidden="true"></i>').
               replace('5', '<i class="fa fa-calculator" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="issues">1 2 3 4 5</div>
<div class="issues">2 3 4</div>
<div class="issues">1 </div>
<div class="issues">1 4 5</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly on the test page I'm using. However when I'm using it in the production page it won't load, unless I copy past it in the console.

Comment: Try placing it within a `$(function() { ... }` block like I've now done in my edit.

Comment: Hi Rick I tried that and it still won't load  - even in console it shows another script doing a data fetch and then it loads. Then the other script keeps on loading and writes over what it did.  If I had hair I would pull it out. Now I'm trying to get it to trigger the script last.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out the production server I'm using was preventing the code from loading. I had to create a delay for it to load the script. Thanks for all the help guys.

```
function trigger(){
$('.issues').html(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.replace('1', '<i class=\"fa fa-heartbeat text-danger fa-lg \" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>').
                         replace('2', '<i class=\"fa fa-graduation-cap fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>').
                         replace('3', '<i class=\"fa fa-line-chart text-info fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>').
                         replace('4', '<i class=\"fa fa-balance-scale text-danger fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>').
                         replace('5', '<i class=\"fa fa-plane text-success fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>');
});
```

}
setTimeout(trigger, 3000);